# Why does liquibaseAutoConfiguration register a depenency with entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

The new version of spring-boot and liquibaseAutoConfiguration we just upgraded to is causing us some issues, it fails because it is looking for a non-existent liquibase file to load, we have done out liquibase configuration using our own self written runners in the past that use a different structure.

Anyways, there are a few potential fixes, one of which is to simply disable the liquibaseAutoConfiguration class from running.  I don't believe we need the bean, but I'm a little uncertain about the reason for adding a dependency to entityManager, which makes me wonder if it's doing something we do need.  Here is a [link to the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java)

I'm trying to understand why the LiquibaseJpaDependencyConfiguration class exists.  Why does the entityManagerFactory need to depend on the liquibase bean?  I would think that the entityManager would be unaware of liquibase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity manager factory doesn't care about Liquibase specifically, but it does care that the database has been fully initialized. The dependency that's setup by `LiquibaseJpaDependencyConfiguration` ensures that is the case as it forces Liquibase to run before the entity manager factory is created.